# How to hide print dialog box in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, printing, dialog, adobe

Is it possible to hide the printing dialog in flex? I'm using the class FlexPrintJob.

Here's my code:

```
var print:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();
print.printAsBitmap = true;

if ( print.start() ) {  
 print.addObject( img as UIComponent, FlexPrintJobScaleType.SHOW_ALL );
 print.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use start2() from the printjobs class

```
 import flash.printing.PrintJob;
 import flash.printing.PrintUIOptions;

 var myPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
 var uiOpt:PrintUIOptions = new PrintUIOptions();
 uiOpt.minPage = 1;
 uiOpt.maxPage = 3;
 var accepted:Boolean = myPrintJob.start2(uiOpt);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Radz! Please let me know if there are other alternatives to this. TYIA.