# Silent Print in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, printing, silent

I have a situation here to print one of my reports with given two options to user:

1. Print with Preview
2. Print Silently(No popup to choose for printer; default printer configured will automatically get a print job)

2nd point - How can we implement it in Flex 4?

Any specific code or component or API to be used to achieve it.

I have a button click to send it to Printer..

Any ideas on this if flex supports silent print or skipping of Print Dialog of Adobe Reader and /or we can call javascript externally and invoke silent ptint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that's possible since the print dialog is native and can't be controlled from the Flex app. If this is an AIR app it might be feasible though.

Comment: Is it so? Can we use Javascript in Flex to invoke or alter the presence of Print Dialog box?

Comment: You can invoke JavaScript through [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to do whatever JavaScript can do. I don't know if JS can do what you whant, but realise that since you would be delegating the print job to another application, you may be limited in what view of your application you can actually print (depends on your specific situation though).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10479655/842112

Comment: Can i have a real time example or jsfiddle for this kind of implementation?

Comment: Any ideas on this if flex supports silent print or skipping of Print Dialog of Adobe Reader and /or we can call javascript externally and invoke silent ptint?