# Print and hide dialogue with Flex/ActionScript/Air - PrintUIOptions not found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I want to print with flex/air - the normal print dialogue works.. But when I start to use start2, I get following error:

```
/Users/myuser/Test2.as:9
Warning: Definition flash.printing.PrintUIOptions could not be found.
      import flash.printing.PrintUIOptions;
             ^

/Users/myuser/Test2.as:12
Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: PrintUIOptions.
      var uiOpt:PrintUIOptions = new PrintUIOptions();
                ^

/Users/myuser/Test2.as:12
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method PrintUIOptions.
      var uiOpt:PrintUIOptions = new PrintUIOptions();
                                     ^

/Users/myuser/Test2.as:15
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method start2 through a reference with static type PrintJob.
      var accepted:Boolean = myPrintJob.start2(uiOpt);
                                        ^
```

And this is my class:

```
package {

  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class Test2 extends Sprite {

    public function Test2 () {
      import flash.printing.PrintJob;
      import flash.printing.PrintUIOptions;

      var myPrintJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
      var uiOpt:PrintUIOptions = new PrintUIOptions();
      uiOpt.minPage = 1;
      uiOpt.maxPage = 3;
      var accepted:Boolean = myPrintJob.start2(uiOpt);
    }
  }
}
```

When I look at this SO answer, it should be easily possible: [How to hide print dialog box in Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477703/how-to-hide-print-dialog-box-in-flex)

I cannot find anymore infos in the web, maybe someone  has a hint for me?

Edit: I'm compiling the whole thing with this command from the commandline:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Apache\\ Flex/bin/mxmlc -o ${file_base_name}.swf ${file}

# but tried also this

/Users/user/Documents/Apache\\ Flex/bin/amxmlc -o ${file_base_name}.swf ${file}
```

Compilation works fine with amxmlc, but then I get strange exceptions when I try to print the documents.

Comment: Just a wild guess: you are running it in a browser/standalone Flash Player.

Comment: This error occures whan I compile the actionscript file! not during runtime.

Comment: Ah. Then you most probably build it as AS3 application while you should build it as AIR application: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS144092a96ffef7cc4c0afd1212601c9a36f-8000.html

Comment: Can you please share how you created the project? Like Target platform: Web/Desktop/Mobile, Output type: Application/Library and the most importantly Flex/AIR SDK:? It seems like you don't have correct SDK.